# Spring Bean error

Tags: java, spring, maven, configuration, spring-bean

I have the following Spring Bean defined:

```
<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.TicketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy"
      c:maxTimeToLive="${tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds:32400}" c:timeToKill="${tgt.timeToKillInSeconds:32400}" c:timeUnit-ref="SECONDS" />
```

That corresponds to [this bean](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/master/cas-server-core/src/main/java/org/jasig/cas/ticket/support/TicketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy.java). With the above configuration, I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grantingTicketExpirationPolicy' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketExpirationPolicies.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:979)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    <long stack trace omitted for brevity>
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So all I did was copy from this example file and change:

```
<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.TicketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy"
      c:maxTimeToLive="${tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds:28800}" c:timeToKill="${tgt.timeToKillInSeconds:7200}" c:timeUnit-ref="SECONDS" />
```

To:

```
<bean id="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.TicketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy"
      c:maxTimeToLive="${tgt.maxTimeToLiveInSeconds:32400}" c:timeToKill="${tgt.timeToKillInSeconds:32400}" c:timeUnit-ref="SECONDS" />
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: So, what happens if you don't change anything? Does it work then?

Comment: Thanks @Hille (+1) - this is CAS so it uses Maven Overlay. If I dont provide a XML Spring Beans file it will use a default. If I provide my own file then it has to define all the beans supported by the default.

Answer (score -1):

the constructor with the params you are using might not exist. Look at the `TicketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy` for available constructors and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I did - thats why I posted a link to it. My question is: I am using the provided constructor, so what is going wrong here?